# decorating our page

Tags: feature-request, site-promotion, beta

I just visited English language SE [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/). the appearance of the page is quite catchy. can we do something like that for our Beta page? will it be good to attract more traffic, resulting in increased possibility of more discussion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, English SE is not a Beta site, it is a full-blown site designed by a professional UI designer commissioned by Stack Exchange company. All Beta sites look the same, by design. We need to prove that this community is sustainable before the site can graduate from Beta.

Comment: where are we standing right now?

Comment: @sangharsh Current beta status is discussed in [this topic](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/317/254). The site has been running for about 100 days? Sites might spend more than a year in Beta.